# Effect of noise data matrix on SVD

Tags: svd, matrix-norms, noise

I am trying to understand the effect of noise data on matrix. Here is the question,

I have $n \times d$ matrix A with rank r with SVD

> A = USV^T

Now, by adding noise matric E of shape (nxd) I get a new matrix A1 = A + E, with rank r1.

$$A_1 = U_1S_1V_1^T$$

Suppose from $A_1$ matrix, only the top r (rank of A) entries are selected. So, that will be

$$\hat{A} = U_1\hat{S}V_1^T$$

I have to prove that,

> ||A(hat) - A||F (Frobenius norm) <= √8r * ||E||2 (2-norm)

I would really appreciate help. I am not getting the intuition on how to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I have Latex-transformed some of your formulas. Please, see how and do the same for the last ones.